# Example of a converging sequence of random variables such that $E[X_n] \rightarrow E[X]$ but not $E[|X_n|] \rightarrow E[|X|]$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have to find a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_n$ which converges in probability to $X$,  such that $E[X_n] \rightarrow E[X]$ but $E[|X_n|]\not\rightarrow E[|X|]$.

I'm honestly quite lost on this. I managed to find some sequences for which the last two conditions hold, but I cannot satisfy the convergence in probability. I think it could be useful to apply the characterization between convergence almost surely and convergence in probability: $X_n\rightarrow X$ in probability iff there exists a subsequence such that $X_{n_k} \rightarrow X$ almost surely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $X_n = n \cdot\text{sgn}(x)\chi_{[-1/n,1/n]}(x)$, that is, a real function that is $0$ outside $[-1/n,1/n]$, takes value $-n$ on $[-1/n,0)$ and $n$ on $(0,1/n]$. Consider the Lebegue measure.

You have that $X_n \to X \equiv 0$ in probability, and $\mathbb E[X_n]=0$, but $\mathbb E[|X_n|] = 2$